# How to pause videos with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, video

So i have a small problem in my website, first of all i made it with **Wordpress**, and i have a page with tabs every tab contain a video **embedded** from **Youtube**, my problem is when i passed from a tab to another the previous video doesn't stop, this is my code :

```
[tabgroup][tab title="Sport"]
 [embedyt]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVsgso273EE?theme=light[/embedyt][/tab]
[/tab]

[tab title="Action"]
 [embedyt]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zuzaxlddWbk?theme=light[/embedyt][/tab]
[/tab]

[tab title="Strategi"]
 [embedyt]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKrRCADS7To?theme=light[/embedyt][/tab]
[/tab]
[/tabgroup]
```

and this is my page to understand the situation [My-website](http://www.alliance-econnect.com/preview/LetsPlay/)

in my website you will find the videos tabs if you click in the **SPIL** menu item.
so plz if someone has any idea to do that i will be very appreciative :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Youtube JavaScript API to do stuff like play, pause, seek to a certain time in a video, set the volume, mute the player, and other useful functions.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference

Just attach an event handler to your tabs that when clicked, get a reference to the current video, pause it then play the new one.

Here's a live demo of such functionality: https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo

Answer (score 1):

If you are  using HTML video tag you can use the code given below

```
var myVideo=document.getElementById("video1"); 
function playVid()
  { 
  myVideo.play(); 
  } 

function pauseVid()
  { 
  myVideo.pause(); 
  }
```

Follow the given link as example http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_met_play_pause